# Commutative function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function in haskell which would not mind in what order I provide it its argument, for example, I want to unify these two functions

```
    reproduce1 :: Male -> Female -> Child
    reproduce2 :: Female -> Male -> Child
```

by one function 'reproduce'.

Comment: This seems a strange request. What is your underlying aim that you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Is the compiler supposed to behave progressively or more after the fashion of the Catholic Church? (That is, what kind of failure should occur when you try to call it with two `Male`s / two `Female`s: simply some kind of non-child-`Child` or a compile-time error?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using a multi-parameter type class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Reproduce x y where
  reproduce :: x -> y -> Child

instance Reproduce Male Female where
  reproduce = reproduce1

instance Reproduce Female Male where
  reproduce = reproduce2
```

However, I'm curious about *why* you would want to do this.

Comment: Such situation occurs in many systems where you dont care in what order you process input. More importantly, in formal verfication, often you have to show f(a,b) == f(b,a)!

Comment: @Dilawar: Yes, but usually that means that `a` and `b` are of the same type, which is not the case here.

Comment: Consider a small circuit with two input and one output wires. Its input wires are coming from different blocks A and B. I am making a distinction between two wires coming from two different blocks so my function is myCircuit :: wireA -> wireB -> outputWire . It helps me keep thr track of topology and I can easily prove some property also. I have give you my top secret :-p

Comment: But does it make sense for the two wires to have different types? And what about the "child" wire? Does it have the same type as one of its "parents", or is it a third type? Are you sure you don't want them all to be of some type `Wire`?

Comment: No I am not sure. I want to do some analysis before making a conclusion.

Comment: I don't think any of the hardware DSLs embedded in Haskell (Lava, Hawk, Wired...) have different types for wires.

Comment: Yes, they don't! I am just playing with an idea. It is more of bheavioural theory over digital system than specification of VLSI systems. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you'd like to package your arguments into a datatype and use [records](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.1.2) (see "Labelled Fields") instead?

```
   data Args = A { m :: Male , f :: Female}
   reproduce :: Args -> Child
```

However, I share @hammar's curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about something like this, which throws an exception if both adults are of the same sex:

```
module Main where

main = putStrLn (reproduce (Male "a") (Female "b"))

type Child = String
data Adult = Male String | Female String
  deriving (Show)

reproduce :: Adult -> Adult -> Child
reproduce (Male a) (Female b) = a ++ "+" ++ b
reproduce (Female a) (Male b) = b ++ "+" ++ a
```

Comment: Most of us have taken Dilawar literally in that he is talking about different types, in which case you can't do pattern matching on the function level (but in type classes, like @hammar).

Comment: Hm, ok I didn't get that from the question, I was assuming he was just talking about arguments.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi, but maybe it would make more sense to change the design so that Male and Female are *not* different types, but instead, two different constructors for the same type. Doing that is pretty awkward in many other languages so if the OP is coming from a background in another language, doing it this way may not have occurred to them.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend fixing the order, say first Male and then Female, or making a "marriage" datatype as in ShiDoSi's solution.

However, check section "Session types and duality", pg 12 in the paper ["Fun with type functions"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.173.6043&rep=rep1&type=pdf) - I think *that* is a good example where you need types coupled in symmetric pairs male-female.